# Excel VBA to auto update sort, sort on multiple columns, AND apply to a "specific range"

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have the following code that dos what I want except for being applied to a specific range. In other words, it does sort on multiple columns, and it does auto update when data is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:F")) Is Nothing Then
Columns("A:Z").Sort Key1:=Range("F3"), Key2:=Range("E3"), Key3:=Range("D3"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End Sub
```

However, what it does is that it is applied to the whole range of "A:Z", whereas I want it to be applied to a specific range only (say, "A3:Z").

I have very limited knowledge of Excel VBAs, and did what I thought was the solution, changing `Columns("A:Z").Sort` to `Columns("A3:Z").Sort`, and `Range("A3:Z").Sort`, but the code stops working after this change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "A3:Z" does not have any meaning in VBA. What are you trying to do, in fact? Do you want using the range starting from A3 To last cell on column Z:Z? Do all the columns in the sheet have the same number of rows?

Comment: Yes, trying to use exactly what you described. And yes, they all have the same number of rows.

Comment: Then, please try the solution I recommended in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try replacing of

```
Columns("A3:Z").Sort
```

with

```
Range("A3:Z" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Sort
```

This will set the range to be sorted like starting from A3 to last cell in column Z:Z, but based on the last cell in column A:A.

**Edited:**

Your event code should look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:F" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B2:Z" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), Key2:=Range("E2"), Key3:=Range("D2"), _
                                                            Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
                                                            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
 End If
End Sub
```

Please, copy the above code instead of yours and test it. When you set the range for the second row, of course, the Keys should be adapted to this row, too. And your code should neve reach the sorting part using `Range("D3:F")`.

Besides all that, you **never** should use **On error resume next** until you have a working code and need **after that** to create a error handler. Otherwise, it only not let you seeing the code real problems/errors...

**Edited:**

You can also use the next approach (using `SortFields`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:F" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveSheet
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("F3:F" & Rows.Count) _
                 , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E3:E" & Rows.Count) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D3:D" & Rows.Count) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Range("B2:Z" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
  End With
 End If
End Sub
```

I think it is obvious that you should choose between one of them. If both of them on the sheet code module, an error will be raised...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did not work. (Also, I added a ")" before .Sort I guess it was missing?

Comment: @lovestacksflow No, no... Please refresh the page (this one) and see the real code I suggested. First time, I just copied your wrong code and also kept "Columns(", by mistake...

Comment: Thanks again. It does work now, but then doesn't auto-update when a new entry is added in the 4th row

Comment: Sorry for the headache, but if at all possible to take a look at the sample file, what I essentially want to do is to keep the column titles without putting the column titles in the first row and using `Header:=xlYes`

Comment: @lovestacksflow It should "auto-update". It determines all the time the last existing row and and build the range starting from the third row to the last containing values. I do not understand where to look "at the sample file", anyhow...

Comment: Thanks. I have attached the sample file in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BNKt8tWe5EId9OrxTan003waZDr7lFGp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @lovestacksflow I refreshed the page and I could see it. But not sure what you mean... If you need the header too, you should use the range starting from the second row: `Range("A2:Z" & Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Sort`. If "to keep the column titles without putting the column titles in the first row" means to have the headers on the second row.

Comment: I refreshed the explanation in the description. My goal is to keep the column titles constant and not moving up and down after sorting is done.

Comment: But, starting from the second row (the one keeping the headers) and using `Header:=xlYes` it should not move the headers... Can you post a link with a real xlsm file, having the code you are using? With dummy data, of course, if something confidential in the original one...

Comment: Sure, I just added the xlsm file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jS5LECkH443YWi7sd7aS3sp5nGfTqOtJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @lovestacksflow OK. I will download it and see where the problem is. I hope you used the recent code (suggested by me), not the original not working one...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the latest code is used indeed.

Comment: @lovestacksflow But, you sent a workbook using a mixture of a pseudo code... Then, having one single row per 'Deadline', which looks to be the primary key, what to be sorted on the other columns, to check the code? And, why the range of columns "A:Z", since there are values only in columns "A:J"? Anyhow, I will adapt the code to work and you will test it on your real environment...

Comment: @lovestacksflow Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: You're right, the range is set to "A:Z", but could be "A:J". I used the code you updated in the following manner: downloaded my file, removed my VBA, pasted yours. It does not auto-update when entering a new value for deadline. Does it on your end?

Comment: @lovestacksflow Sorry, I left home for a period. I did not test the code, because I was sure that it works. Now tried it and I could observe that **your sheet does not have anything in column A:A**. So, counting the rows in this column made the filter to be applied only on the headers... I adapted the code to filter according to B:B column number of rows... I also added 1 to the calculated number of rows, in order to include the one where you intent to add new values (without initially writing in column B:B...). I will also post a piece of code sorting in a different way (using `SortFields`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233972/discussion-between-lovestacksflow-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone really naïve like me had the same problem, here's what works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:F")) Is Nothing Then
Range("A3", Range("Z3").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("F3"), Key2:=Range("E3"), Key3:=Range("D3"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Order2:=xlAscending, Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End If
End Sub
```

Applying the formula to all the rows below A3